# How to attach my webpage to another webpage, just as chat window is attached to gmail.com?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, tornado

I have designed a chat application that runs on tornado. I can open this in my browser as localhost:8000.  Now I need to attach this chat window to my webpage, just as gmail and facebook has chat attached to their web page with separate 'minimise' and 'close' buttons .

I tried using the jquerychat plugin, but in its documentation it does not give provision for adding any website links to be opened like a chat window in bottom right corner, as my case demands. How can I do it?

Comment: I have tried iframe. but the problem is I want it like 2 webpages in parallel .Just as facebook , gmail chat , where minimise button in  the main gmail.com , it minimises the window along with chat and ,even i have provision of minimising chat window alone , without affecting main window . Iframe does it by making the second page occupy some space in first page . but here no page occupies space on the other , only some portion on main page is not visible .but what i need are parallel windows

Comment: wrap iframe in a container div in the page and add some control buttons to do whatever it is you need to do with the container